# Hide header on StackNavigator with React Navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
          title="Chat with Lucy"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Chat with Lucy</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
  },
  Chat: {
    screen: ChatScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Chat with Lucy'
    }
  },
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <SimpleApp />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

On `HomeScreen` there's a header now that looks like this:

[image]

How do I hide this header? I just want a blank screen, or in this case, just the `<Text>Hello, Chat App!</Text>` to show?

Answer (score 32):

if you want to hide all screen header then use @pitty or @burhan answers (although both have same answer) but for specifically remove a screen header then just use `header: null` for the screen props as mentioned in the documentation of [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#header) so use it like this:

```
Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
      header: null //this will hide the header
    },
},
```

**Update February 2020**
With [new release of stack](https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/releases/tag/v2.0.1) now you need to use param `headerShown` which default is true e.g.

```
Home: {
     screen: HomeScreen,
     navigationOptions: {
       title: 'Home',
       headerShown: false
     },
},
```

Answer (score 7):

try to add `{ headerMode: 'none' }`
in your `stactNavigator`

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
  },
  Chat: {
    screen: ChatScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Chat with Lucy'
    }
  },
}, {headerMode: 'none'});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Home'
        },
      },
      Chat: {
        screen: ChatScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'Chat with Lucy'
        }
      },
{ headerMode: 'none'}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Version: 5.x

**headerShown**
Whether to show or hide the header for the screen. The header is shown by default unless:

The **headerMode** prop on the navigator was set to none.
The screen is in a stack nested in another stack navigator's screen which has a header.
Setting this to **false** hides the header. When the header is hidden in a nested stack, you can explicitly set it to true to show it.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: '',
      headerTransparent:true,
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice **options={{headerShown: false}}**   in the below code. It's working with the latest version(^5.9.0) with me. Thank you.

```
const App = () => {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in stackNavigator you can use the `headerMode: 'none'` to hide the header. And one more thing, you can take this as a suggestion, use

> react-native-router-flux

which would be more easy to use in case of navigations in react-native, and in there you can hide the header using the **hideNavBar** prop to the scenes
and here is the documentation which would be helpful to you on the same [Documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md)

Answer (score 0):

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
LandingPage: LandingPage,
HomeScreen: HomeScreen,
Login: Login
},
{
initialRouteName: 'LandingPage',
**header: null,
headerMode: 'none'**
}
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Your navigation options should look something like this, just add the bold lines in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`headerMode: 'none'` doesn't work with the latest React Navigation. To disable the **default header of the top screen** set
`screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}` on the navigator:

```
    <SpaceStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
      <SpaceStack.Screen name="Workspaces" component={WorkspaceScreen} />
      <SpaceStack.Screen name="Details" component={WorkspaceDetailScreen} />
    </SpaceStack.Navigator>
```

To disable **other headers (set by children or other navigators)** set
`options={{ headerShown: false }}` on the screen:

```
    <SpaceStack.Navigator>
      <SpaceStack.Screen name="Workspaces" component={WorkspaceScreen} />
      <SpaceStack.Screen name="Details" options={{ headerShown: false }} component={WorkspaceDetailScreen} />
    </SpaceStack.Navigator>
```

To disable headers from **childrens of nested navigators**, though it would dismiss it from other screens of the same stack once runned, set this in the child component:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent().setOptions({ header: () => null });
  });
```