# I want to hide the header in react native expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to hide the header but it does not. and it keeps showing a title of index even there is not title ?

```
import IndexScreen from './src/screens/index'
    import React from 'react';
    import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
    import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'
    const navigator = createStackNavigator({
        index:IndexScreen,
    },{
        initialRouteName:"index",
        defaultNavigationOption:{
          header: null
        }
    }
    )
    export default createAppContainer(navigator)
```

Comment: which version of navigation you're using ?

Comment: old version I think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441620/hide-header-on-stacknavigator-with-react-navigation-in-react-native/48442173